Condensing history table for teradata SQL
I have a history table that tracks all sorts of changes to different fields. I only need to analyze the changes to [MTN_STATUS_IND]. Because it's a history table that tracks a lot of changes there will be multiple rows with the same [MTN_STATUS_IND], but with different date ranges. So the [EFF_DT] and [EXP_DT] need to be "condensed" to 1 record for every given [MTN_STATUS_IND] and [KEY_c].
To put it more concisely: For any given [KEY_c] and [MTN_STATUS_IND], condense the data to 1 record with the min [EFF_DT] and max [EXP_DT] while maintaining the correct chronological order and the changes that occur in [MTN_STATUS_IND].
Example
Thanks for any help!
-C
Here's a screenshot of an example.

Welcome to SO!  Please don't link to or post screen shots.  Add some sample data and desired results as text.

This is easy to do with Teradata's NORMALIZE feature. That requires a PERIOD data type instead of separate DATE fields, but it's not hard to convert:
WITH normalized_using_period as
(SELECT NORMALIZE KEY_c, MTN_STATUS_IND, 
-- PERIOD does not include ending bound so adjust "closed" periods
   PERIOD(EFF_DT,CASE WHEN EXP_DT < date'9999-12-31' THEN NEXT(EXP_DT) ELSE EXP_DT END) as PD
 FROM my_history_table
   )
-- The hard part is done, just split PERIOD and re-adjust   
SELECT KEY_c, MTN_STATUS_IND, 
    BEGIN(PD) as EFF_DT,   
    CASE WHEN END(PD) < DATE'9999-12-31' THEN PRIOR(END(PD)) ELSE END(PD) END as EXP_DT
FROM normalized_using_period
ORDER BY KEY_c, EFF_DT DESC;


Tiny improvement: No CASE required in the 2nd Select, DATE' 9999-12-31' in a period indicates infinity, not the actual date. When you use last(pd) you get the last included date (same as prior(end(pd))), but for the infinity date it's still infinity, i.e. DATE' 9999-12-31'.
